# Moving by word no longer working in Word for Mac 2011

Tags: ms-office

In Microsoft Word for Mac 2011, previously <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+arrow moved the cursor one word left/right. Recently, this function no longer works on my iMac. Is there a fix?

Comment: it's opt/arrow... always was

Comment: opt/arrow now only moves the cursor one space/character in my version of MS Word for Mac 2011.  I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you installed any kind of 'keyboard commander' software recently? BetterTouch, Karabiner, 3rd party mouse/keyboard drivers etc? Also specifically what machine & OS?

Comment: Have you verified that your Option button works as it should?  For instance, go to the File Menu of any application.  When you see the drop down, press the Option button.  You should see some different options appear.  Same goes for the arrow....

Comment: Check your Keyboard Shortcuts in System Preferences to see that there has not been a key combination set that conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Microsoft's keyboard site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Word-keyboard-shortcuts-c0ca851f-3d58-4ce0-9867-799df73666a7) for Office 2011:

[image]

Comment: Yes.  I found and read that.  However, as I have been saying, the Option/Arrow function no longer works on my program.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you try reinstalling Word?